# How can I solve some certain Inequalities

Tags: inequality

I am not able to prove the following Inequality:
$$b(x^{1/b}-1)< a(x^{1/a}-1)$$
if $x>0$, $x \neq 1$, and $0<a<b$.

I have tried and am still trying to use the inequality
$$\left(1 + \frac{x}{a}\right)^a < \left(1+ \frac{x}{b}\right)^b$$
but so far I did not get anything. Your help is much much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to go is to use the generalized mean value theorem (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy%27s_mean_value_theorem)):

$$\frac{x^{\frac 1a}-1}{x^{\frac 1b}-1} = \frac ba \frac{\xi^{\frac 1a -1}}{\xi^{\frac 1b -1}} = \frac ba \cdot \xi^{\frac 1a - \frac 1b}=\frac ba \cdot \xi^{\alpha} \text{ with } \alpha >0$$

$$x>1\Rightarrow 1<\xi<x \Rightarrow \frac{x^{\frac 1a}-1}{x^{\frac 1b}-1} > \frac ba$$

$$0<x<1\Rightarrow x<\xi<1 \Rightarrow \frac{x^{\frac 1a}-1}{x^{\frac 1b}-1} < \frac ba \stackrel{x^{\frac 1b}-1<0}{\rightarrow} x^{\frac 1a}-1 > \frac ba (x^{\frac 1b}-1)$$